# hasClass is not working when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to say if `body` has x class to add x class.

**Javascript**

```
$('body').toggleClass('projectLoaded');
$('[data-type="projectLoader"]').click(function() {
  var proj = $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-project');
  $('#arrow-nav').addClass('slideIn');

  updateHash(proj);
  return false;
});
$('[data-type="projectDie"]').click(function() {

  $('body').removeClass('projectLoaded');
  $('#arrow-nav').removeClass('slideIn');
  return false;
});

if ($('body').hasClass('projectLoaded')) {
  $('#arrow-nav').addClass('slideIn');
} else {
  $('#arrow-nav').removeClass('slideIn');
}
```

When `projectLoaded` is triggered, the `addClass` does work for `slideIn`, but when I refresh, even though `projectLoaded` is active, the `addClass` disappears. I thought a `hasClass` would work but it doesn't. Everything works but, it's just on refresh it disappears.

Working page [here](http://darrenbachan.com/), click a project and you'll `#arrow-nav.slideIn` working, but refresh and the `.slideIn` isn't added.

**UPDATE**
This is what worked for me:

```
$( 'document' ).ready(function() {
        if ($('body').hasClass('projectLoaded')) {
            $('#arrow-nav').addClass('slideIn');
        } else {
            $('#arrow-nav').removeClass('slideIn');
        }
});
```

or

```
$( 'body.projectLoaded' ).ready(function() {
    $('#arrow-nav').addClass('slideIn');
});
```

If this is not proper or there's a more efficient way of doing this please submit it below.

Comment: Have you tried putting the code inside document.ready function()?

Comment: Can you show us some working code, so that it will be easier to debug.

Comment: Some HTML, some HTML, my kingdom for some HTML!

Comment: @Darren what type of language is javascript?

Comment: @titi23 I upaded my original post.

Comment: @DarrenBachan have you checked, when you are trying to add class to #arrow-nav, is it already present by that time? If you are trying to add class to an element which is not present, it wont work I think. Also what "if ($('body').hasClass('projectLoaded'))" condition is returning? Already body is having the class or not, please check.

Comment: @titi23 the hasClass isn't working there, it was added to try to make the .slideIn class on body appear on refresh. Also, I have checked, and .slideIn isn't on #arrow-nav until .projectLoaded is on the body.

Comment: @DarrenBachan can you create one fiddle reproducing the problem. So that we can debug and help you? One more thing is try adding the class to  #arrow-nav inside document.ready. This may work.

Comment: @titi23 I tried that, but when I refreshed the homepage that, for some reason, triggered the .slideIn on #arrow-nav even though .projectLoaded wasn't on body. A fiddle, I think it's a bit complex to get this working, would you mind taking a look at the link I have in my post? It has a url to the problem.

Comment: As I can see on refresh or opening the same link in different tab is coming with "projectLoad" class in body. Are you adding the class to the body on loading the page itself? Have you tried adding "$('body').toggleClass('projectLoaded');" inside document.ready?

Comment: @titi23 Yeah, that didn't work. It breaks the entire site when I try. It can't toggle because it executes .projectLoaded right away, currently the js I have is set up so when .projectLoader is clicked, the body gets .projectLoaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checking ready as follows may help

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('body').toggleClass('projectLoaded');
});
```

My instinct tells me this will work to, but didnt test it.

```
$( 'body' ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('body').toggleClass('projectLoaded');
});
```

Comment: Both were working fine as I was't sure about `body ready function` so I created [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxavrws0/) for to test it and its working fine.

Comment: @Kirankumar If I do this, and swap alert for an addClass, when on the homepage, where .projectLoaded is no longer on body, it still remains. Refreshing won't remove the class.

Comment: Is it possible that a double call is happening here, I had a similar experience, and by adding unbind to the click call, fixed the issue.

$('[data-type="projectDie"]').unbind('click').click(function() { ... }

Comment: I got it. On document ready if body has class .projectLoaded add .slideIn on #arrow-nav else remove it. I think it would even work if i changed document to body. It also worked if I did on  body.projectLoaded ready add .slideIn on #arrow-nav. This answer seems to be the closest. I am still very new to javascript, I am not sure how I would make an unbind work.

Comment: the unbind just prevents a double click action happen, that sometimes can be triggered on some browsers. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

$('body').toggleClass('projectLoaded') is given with in the function loadProject() which is executed after the hasClass condition is checked. So before the class 'projectLoaded' is added in the body the hasClass condition is exceuted, so the class 'slideIn' is not added. Try this statement '$('body').toggleClass('projectLoaded')' in the document ready just like above. It will work.

Comment: Everyone is suggesting this, the site breaks when I do this. This executes .projectLoaded right away and it's only supposed to be added during a click event on .projectLoader.